# Getting the value of a pointer to a structure to another pointer to a structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

..then to an array, or along those lines. I'm so confused on what I'm supposed to do.

Here are the structs:

```
typedef struct {
  char name[30];
} PersonType;

typedef struct {
  PersonType *personInfo;
} StudentType;

typedef struct {
  StudentType students[30];
} GraduateType;
```

I want to get the name of the PersonType. Something like this, in main():

```
GraduateType *gptr = (GraduateType *) calloc(3, sizeof(GraduateType));
// Assume here that info has been scanf()'d
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    if(strcmp(gptr[i].students[j].personInfo.name, "asd")) { // <- This
      // blah
    }
  }
}
```

How?

Comment: I'm assuming since you're asking that your current line doesn't work. Do you get any errors building that?

Comment: @Xyon Yup, but it was an "invalid type of argument '->'" error--I was just confused on the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. `personInfo` is a pointer, so you should treat it as such:

```
gptr[i].students[j].personInfo->name
```

Comment: I want to remove my previous comment about the error but can't manage it--but thank you, this does work, I just put the -> elsewhere accidentally when reading.